# Library for converting word representations of numbers into numbers

Tags: numbers

Searching for "word to number" almost always ends up giving results for converting numbers into word representations which seems a much simpler task than the inverse. There are some pretty trivial cases which could be handled with a basic lookup table ("first,1st,one" -> 1, etc.), but I'm looking for something which is better at tackling the general case. The app which I'm building involves taking user input which may or may not include a number and comparing that with a known result (which itself is stored as text), so for even more complexity it'd be preferable if it were able to deal with misspellings as well (e.g. frist, sceond) however this could probably be accomplished by passing the input through a spell checker first).

So far I've found http://j.mearie.org/post/7462182919/spelt-number-to-decimal which seems pretty cool because it seems to support some other languages (or not), but I would prefer something that was more portable and less obfuscated.

The most sophisticated one I've found is https://github.com/ged/linguistics/blob/master/lib/linguistics/en/numbers.rb and http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=506028 also seems promising.

Is there any more complete library out there? I'd like it to handle english and spanish numbers in different formats such as first, 1st, 1, one and even invalid ones like 1nd, and roman numerals like MMXII.

Answer (score 1):

Given you're hoping to convert from human language into math, and not the other way around, you're basically in need of giant tables/sets of enums.  Math is based on logic and the rule set is taken to point to words when going one way.  Moving backwards from language which is a set of agreed upon rules (see english language for illogical exceptions to every rule) the only sure way of accomplishing is gathering together every possible way of referring to a number, and tying it in a translation map.

Any library you find will not only have to be updated over time to accept new forms of talking about numbers, but also possibly negating or changing previous rules that have changed.

How do you even plan to handle invalid input like 1nd?  Did they mean 1 or 2?  This is a glimpse of the reason why entire PhD thesis are devoted to natural language processing.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into Lex & Yacc for this kind of things. 
I think some "human calculators" are already written (even if I can't find it at the moment) so you could extract the number comprehension out of it.